# Buscar resultados cruzados em tabelas relacionadas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Criei várias tabelas:

**Usuários:**

```
chave primária
email
senha
```

**Detalhe Físico:**

```
user_id
altura
```

**Dados Pessoais:**

```
user_id
estado_civil
```

Agora estou tendo dificuldades em buscar resultados cruzados.

Exemplo: localizar usuários com `altura = 170` e ao mesmo tempo com `estado_civil = casado`.

Tentei agrupar as `wheres`, mas tá ficando um pouco complexo, e pior, o resultados só traz valores da primeira tabela.

Comment: Poderia postar o que você já tentou ?

Comment: Você deve passar os 3 Models as 3 Tabelas e o resultado esperado pelo visto é muito simples a sua dúvida são `join` e um `select` com os campos que você deseja trazer, Pelo Model UsurarioPrincipal dá para trazer todas as informações. Para que eu não fique editando resposta passe os models e as tabelas por favor!

Answer (score 2):

Eu crio o model mas sempre chamo o que preciso no model. Vou deixar o código só com a parte que você precisa

## Modelo Segundo o Site do Laravel

```
DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.id', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

## Controller Qualquer

```
$variavel = ModelUsuarios::join('tabeladadospessoais', 'ModelUsuarios.id', '=', 'tabeladadospessoais.user_id')->select('tabeladadospessoais.email', 'tabeladadospessoais.nome', 'tabeladadospessoais.endereco')->get();
```

Ai depois é só mandar chamar a view.

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('nome.view')->with('registro',$variavel);
```

OBS: Não esquecer de usar o "Use" e colocar o nome do model(ModelUsuarios).